# How to Compress/Decompress payload in Mule and get back original payload

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I was doing some sort of  POC with Mule Gzip compressor and de-compressor.. My Mule flow is following

```
<flow name="GZipCompress" doc:name="GZipFlow1">
  <file:inbound-endpoint path="E:\backup\test" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File">
    <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="anirban.doc" caseSensitive="false"/>
   </file:inbound-endpoint>

 <string-to-byte-array-transformer doc:name="String to Byte Array"/>
 <gzip-compress-transformer/>
  <file:outbound-endpoint path="E:\backup\test\ss" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
 </flow>



 <flow name="GZipUnCompress" doc:name="GZipFlow2">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="E:\backup\test\ss" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File">
         <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="anirban.doc" caseSensitive="false"/>
   </file:inbound-endpoint>
   <gzip-uncompress-transformer />
  <byte-array-to-string-transformer />
   <file:outbound-endpoint path="E:\backup\test\ss\New folder" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
</flow>
</mule>
```

Now the issue is I have a file **anirban.doc** which is around **80.0 KB** before compression .. When I put the file in the folder for compression, file inbound of GZipCompress flow picks it up and compress it .. After compression the file size gets around **20 KB** which is fine .. Now when I try to unCompress the file using **GZipUnCompress** flow , I get the file back in output folder of file outbound endpoint  **GZipUnCompress** flow .. And this time the so called uncompress file is of size **96.0 KB** .. and when I try to open the file I get binary format .. So my question is how can I get the uncompressed file back to same as original file size and I can open it and read it and not in binary form but as same original content .. Is this the right way I am compressing and decompressing a file/payload ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remove the `string-to-byte-array-transformer` (which is useless and even counter productive: keep bytes as much as possible), then `GZipCompress` works perfectly fine: it creates a valid gzipped file in the output dir.