# Using Mule, how to create a password-protected .csv file that can be opened with a standard tool?

Tags: mule

I have been asked to create a password-protected .csv file. This would be similar to password protecting in Excel or Word.

An option I suppose would be to create a password-protected .zip of the .csv file. On the recipient's end, they need to open the file using a standard tool like zip/7zip/Excel/etc., where they supply a password.

Is there a straightforward way to do this in Mule?

Comment: You can't password protect a .csv file (it is just a text file after all), so yes, you would have to do it in a .zip file or similar.  I know that Mule has a gzip component (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25771002/how-to-compress-decompress-payload-in-mule-and-get-back-original-payload) , but do not know whether it supports putting a password on it.

Comment: Thanks Dijkgraaf, The file will be used in Excel so I  was thinking more along the lines of a native Excel password lock, just like you can set on an Excel file. I did see the gzip. It only has mime type and encoding, unfortunately no password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use Apache POI to output the encrypted Excel file from a custom Mule component (either a Java, Scripted or MEL component).

See: [Encryption in Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/encryption.html)

Comment: Thank you David, that is a possibility.
At this point, given the complexity-to-value ratio I think we are going to go with user logins on the destination side and not try to password protect the files. I appreciate all the suggestions.